# @XmlElements and @XmlJavaTypeAdapter not working together

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm having a small problem with JAXB unmarshalling in that my input XML can be wrapped by one of two elements, for example:

```
<Output>
  <Update>
      <Channel>
          <id>1</id>
      </Channel>
      <Channel>
          <id>2</id>
      </Channel>
  </Update>
</Output>
```

or

```
<Output>
  <Erase>
      <Channel>
          <id>1</id>
      </Channel>
  </Erase>
</Output>
```

My root class is unmarshalling the *Channels* to a HashMap using an @XmlJavaTypeAdapter and the code below works as expected.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Output")
public class Output{
    @XmlElement(name="Update")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ChannelAdapter.class)
    private HashMap<Long, Channel> allChannels;
    public Map getChannels() {
        return allChannels;
    }
}
```

where *Channels* class is:

```
public class Channels {
    @XmlElement(name="Channel")
    public Channel[] channels;
}
```

and the *Channel* is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Channel {
    @XmlPath("id/text()")
    private Long id;
}
```

and finally the *ChannelAdapter* is:

```
public class ChannelAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Channels, Map<Long, Channel>> {
    @Override
    public Map<Long, Channel> unmarshal(Channels value) { ... }

    @Override
    public Channels marshal(Map<Long, Channel> map) { ... }
}
```

However I thought I could just replace `@XmlElement(name="Update")` with

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="Update"),
    @XmlElement(name="Erase")
})
```

but that results in an empty map.

Hard-coding to either `@XmlElement(name="Update")` or `@XmlElement(name="Erase")` works with one or other the input XML documents but I need something that will work with either of the wrapper elements. I tried using a `@XmlElementWrapper` but that can only be used on a collection or array property which will not work since *allChannels* is a HashMap.

Could I please get an explain of what am I misunderstanding about the `@XmlElements` annotation and also a way to get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, JAXB forces you to have a bidirectional data model; you cannot merge two children of a node into one without breaking this convention. So, you need to have two lists, one for Updates and one for Erases.

Because I've never used @XmlElements annotation, take my comment with care.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your XSDs to something that let's Output incorporate a choice allowing the XML to use either of the elements but never ever both at the same time.

I don't know, however, how to annotate this via XmlElements. Try to build an XSD first an then generate the classes for looking up the annotations ;).